# React Native - Buttons with shadow

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create this button into my React Native project.
[image]

The problem is with that blue shadow. I've already tried packages like react-native-neomorph-shadows. I also tried with:

```
shadowColor: COLORS.primary,
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.25,
shadowRadius: 3.84,

elevation: 5,
```

About this, the problem is that the shadow isn't powerful enough.

Do you have any ideas how can I do this? Thank you!

EDIT: Maybe this helps... In the design file that effect is made by blurring a blue button and positioning it behind the real button. I've tried this also by using react-native-blur package but the result is also bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IOS you won't need any packages you can just use react-native's shadow props described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props

There is also the elevation property for android, but you won't be able to change the color:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#elevation

Here's an IOS example view with a similar shadow effect:

```html
<View style={{
  backgroundColor: '#22A7F0',
  height: 48,
  width: 240,
  borderRadius: 10,
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  shadowRadius: 10,
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
  shadowColor: '#22A7F0',
}}/>
```

It is noteworthy that the sample you provided combines both a shadow effect and a LinearGradient, so you may want to look into that as well.